# How can I deregister a car in Austria?

Tags: car, austria, departure

I have a car with Austin number plates, and I want to know how it would be better to proceed to do things legally.
I'm moving to Belgium for work, and I would like to take the car with me. Should I deregister here first? Or is enough if I register the car in Belgium and like that would get automatically deregistered from here?
If I have to deregister from Austria first, for how long are those number plates available?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you normally get the new registration first, otherwise it would be complicated to get the car to Belgium. You probably have some piece of paper from the Austrian authorities, which might include information about how to de-register.

Comment: I don't think it's automatic. And as part of the deregistration, you have to hand in the number plates, so they are available exactly until then. Also see https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/6/Seite.060900.html